# Spring com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to execute following query which use a regular expression

```
BasicQuery b = new BasicQuery("{ description: /\bmanager\b/}");
```

but it throws com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException

```
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{ description: /manager/}
               ^
    com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:216)
    com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:249)
    com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:213)
    com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:163)
    com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:99)
    com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:79)
```

How do I prevent this error

Answer (score 2):

The /.../ notation for regex isn't valid json.  To use regex in a json document like that you need the form `{ field: { $regex: 'acme.*corp', $options: 'i' }` as shown [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).